# Is it possible to make all Jupyter notebook cells of bash type by default?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

I have only Bash cells in a certain Jupyter notebook which are run using the `%%bash` magic and it works as expected. However, it looks somewhat unpleasant having `%%bash` as the first line in all Bash cells and when converting to an HTML file through Markdown I have to clean up the `%%bash` in the cell as all cells in the notebook are Bash and I don't need to differentiate between Python and Bash.

Is there any plugin that would extend a type of a notebook cell making them all running as Bash without having `%%bash` written in the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the bash kernel. An example is the kernel for the first notebook in the listing, under ‘Start here the first time’, that comes up after clicking `launch Cirocos` [here](https://github.com/fomightez/circos-binder). Note ‘bash’ in upper right corner. Other notebooks in the set use the Python kernel.
Install directions [here](https://github.com/takluyver/bash_kernel).